# Return a downloadable file link given a string with Django

Tags: django

Given a URL string which points to a file on my local nginx instance, how do I make Django return a response that causes the file to be downloaded from nginx?  I don't want Django to be opening up the file and streaming it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `X-Accel-Redirect` header: http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

For example:

```
resp = HttpResponse()
resp['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/static/my_file"
return resp
```

Note that, as per the documentation, you'll need to translate the local path into a URL which nginx can serve.

Comment: So I'm new to this and am a little confused.  My nginx lives at localhost:8001 and apache rewrites all http://localhost/static/file -> http://localhost:8001/file. I tried what you said above (perhaps incorrectly).  Should my x-accel-redirect url have 'localhost:8001' in it?

Comment: You should setup nginx to serve static files from some base directory (ex: `location /static/ {
  internal;
  root   /my/static/files/;
}`), then return an absolute URL that points somewhere in there. For example, if you want to serve `/my/static/files/my_file`, you would use `/static/my_file`.